# Implicit definition of recursive sequence $\displaystyle a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{(3 + (-1)^n)^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> I have to show that the recursive sequence given by
>   $$
> b_1 = 1, ~ b_{n+1} = b_n + \frac{1}{(3 + (-1)^n)^n}
> $$
>   converges.

I can show its convergence by showing its monotone and bounded by 2 but I wondered, if I can find a implicit definition of the sequence without an $(-1)^n$ terms in it.
Obviously, 
$$b_n = b_1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(3 + (-1)^n)^n}$$

I figured out that

> $$
> b_{2n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{1}{16^k} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 4^k} =
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{4^k + 2}{2^{4k+1}}
> $$

which converges by the geometric series test (also WolframAlpha says so), whilst it WolframAlpha doesn't make any statement about the convergence of
$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(3 + (-1)^n)^n}$.

Is there a implicit definition of $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ without the $(-1)^n$, or is that simply not possible?

Comment: $a(n)=\frac{2^{1-2 n} \left(16+39 (-4)^n-35 (-2)^n+45\ 2^n-65\ 4^n\right)}{-75+45 (-1)^n}$ explicit form.

Comment: Some of your formulas are wrong.  From the recursion with $n=1$, one has $$b_2=b_1+{1\over3-1}=1+{1\over2}={3\over2}$$ but $$b_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^n{2^{2k-1}+1\over16^k}$$ gives $$b_2=\sum_{k=0}^2{2^{2k-1}+1\over16^k}={{1\over2}+1\over1}+{2+1\over16}+{8+1\over16^2}={3\over2}+{3\over16}+{9\over256}\not={3\over2}$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How do you arrive at this? Also I asked if its possible to have a explicit for with out any $(-1)^n$s, or any $(-2)^n$s, for that matter.

Comment: With help Human Brain+CAS like Mathematica.  $a(n)=\frac{1}{45} 2^{1-2 n} \left(2^n \left(-35+39\ 2^n\right)+\frac{8 \left(6-5\ 2^n\right)}{-5+3 e^{i n \pi }}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence is increasing. It sufficient to show that it is bounded.

We have $$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac 1{(3+(-1)^n)^n}\leqslant\frac1{2^n}\implies b_n-b_1\leqslant \frac1{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{2^{n-2}}+\ldots+\frac1{2}<1$$

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to find a formula for $b_n$ separating the cases in which $n$ es even or odd. But you do not need this to prove convergence of the series, since
$$
0\le\frac 1{(3+(-1)^n)^n}\le\frac1{2^n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
a_{k+1}-a_1=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{(3+(-1)^n)^n}\tag{1}
$$
But
$$
0\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(3+(-1)^n)^n}=L<\infty
$$
since
$$
\frac{1}{4^n}\leq\frac{1}{(3+(-1)^n)}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
for $n\ge1$. let $k\to\infty$ in (1) to deduce that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{k+1}=\lim_{k\to\infty}(a_{k+1}-a_{1})+\lim_{k\to\
\infty}a_{1}
$$
as desired.